# momentjs display localtime and autoformat string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, momentjs

Is it possible for Momentjs to display the localtime and autoformat the string.

I have eg. the time 2015-03-20T09:08:53+01:00 and want momentjs to display in local time and format this in danish starting DD-MM-YYYY

```
$('[data-momentdate]').each(function () {
                                var localTime = moment.utc($(this).attr('data-momentdate')).toDate();
                                localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                                $(this).html(localTime);
                            });
```

The above code converts the utc time to local danish time, but I want momentjs to determine which format to use based by the timezone

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a UTC date-time string as 2014-02-19 05:24:32 AM and you want to determine time in your timezone then use following code:

moment.utc('2014-02-19 05:24:32 AM').toDate();

toDate() method gives javascript Date() object.

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
    var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  
    //put UTC time into divUTC  
    divUtc.text(moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));      

    //get text from divUTC and conver to local timezone  
    var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    divLocal.text(localTime);        
  },1000);
});
```

For more information look at: [How to get local time from UTC using Moment.JS](http://www.digitoffee.com/programming/get-local-time-utc-using-moment-js/94/).

**Update:**

By default, moment parses and displays in local time. If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment().

```
moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
```

On the other hand, there maybe different format for one timezone and in that case you should give the format. In addition to this, if you want to use the same format you can use globalization property as below on the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />
```

Comment: I want momentjs to determine which format to use based by the timezone

Comment: @user3369534 I updated my code. Could you check it and clarify if it works?

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') and let the timezone decide the correct format ?